# Using grep in shell script

Tags: shell, grep

I have a text file which looks like this(I am showing few lines of it)

```
INDEX : 1
snRNA_seq:TTTTGGAGCAGGGAGATGGAAT

miRNA_seq:CTCCTGACTCCAGGTCCTGTGT

target: RNU2-1,RNU2-64P,RNU2-37P,RNU2-61P,RNU2-68P,RNU2-26P,RNU2-57P,RNU2-59P
length: 22
miRNA: hsa-miR-378a-5p*MI0000786
length: 22


mfe: -21.3 kcal/mol

p-value: 0.015469



position  1

target 5'        U             A 3'

                  UUUGGAG CAGGG    

                  GGACCUC GUCCU    

miRNA  3' UGUGUCCU       A     C 5'





INDEX : 10
snRNA_seq:TTGGAGCAGGGAGATGGAAT

miRNA_seq:ATCCTCTCTTCCCTCCTCCCAG

target: RNU2-1,RNU2-64P,RNU2-37P,RNU2-61P,RNU2-68P,RNU2-26P,RNU2-57P,RNU2-59P
length: 20
miRNA: hsa-miR-7111-3p*MI0022962
length: 22


mfe: -24.0 kcal/mol

p-value: 0.001695



position  2

target 5'   U    C        U    A 3'

             GGAG AGGG AGA  GGA    

             CCUC UCCC UCU  CCU    

miRNA  3' GAC    C    U   CU   A 5'
```

I have list of identifiers namely 1,10,20,30 etc This identifier in the above file is right next to INDEX part. All I want to do is if the identifier matches the above file print that line + next 28 lines basically some thing like this grep -A 28 "INDEX : identifier"

How can i do this in shell??

Regards

Comment: `grep -A 28 "INDEX : identifier"` is exactly how you would do this in a shell script.  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

When you have fixed entries for the identifiers you like, you can use

```
for identifier in 1 10 20 30; do
   grep -A 28 "INDEX : ${identifier}$" Test.txt
done
```

When you do not have fixed identifiers, you might grep without specifying the identifier:

```
grep -A 28 "^INDEX : " Test.txt
```

I use `^` here for matching INDEX lines at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I have Identifiers like 1,2,3,4,5,10,100
No they are arranged in the input file as 1,10,100,101
Since grep goes line by line I am purposely using this
for i in 1 10;do
  grep -A 28 "INDEX : ${i}"
done

It gives me 101 102 103 104 etc why so?? Let's say I want 1 and 2 How will I get that??

Comment: I added an end-of-line character `$`. Without the dollar grep will find `INDEX : 1` as a substring of `INDEX : 101`

Comment: for identifier in 1 2; do
   grep -A 28 "INDEX : ${identifier}$"
done < Test.txt
Does not give INDEX : 2 output
Why so???

Comment: See edited answer: Test.txt should be inside the loop, so each call to grep in the loop will know where to grep.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep` with `-f`:

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.
```

but for that you need to format your `identifiers` file accordingly, e.g. it should read:

```
INDEX : 1
INDEX : 10
..........
INDEX : 100
```

instead of:

```
1,10....100
```

If you use `-` as `FILE` `grep` will read patterns from `stdin` so, one way, with `awk` (and also using `grep` with `-x` to match the whole line):

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print "INDEX : "$i}' identifiers | grep -A28 -x -f - file
```

Unless you want to use your favorite tool to edit `identifiers` in place and then run:

```
grep -A28 -x -f identifiers file
```

Comment: I undeleted this (and a couple of other As you deleted) because they provide useful information. One of them was also the only answer on the Q so deleting it sets the Q as unanswered. If you really, really want to, you can delete them again but I would much prefer you leave them.

Comment: Sure, flag away. The thing is that consecutive question deletions raises an automatic flag (to protect against rage quitting I guess). That's why I noticed. As for ignoring, no. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a multi-pass through your data with a fixed subset of IDs given, this is one possible way (for sample indexes 1, 2, 10):

```
sed -n '/INDEX : \(1\|2\|10\)$/,+28p'
```